# Programmatically get launcher's icon size

Tags: android, icons, launcher, shortcut

I'm trying to programmatically get the launcher's icon size. It differs between devices. I don't have the assets in advance, I'm creating them.

Can I somehow query for the right icon dimensions for the specific launcher?

Comment: If you're creating the assets, then can you simply reference the asset and just do a getWidth/Height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}
```

After getting the density... you will know which launcher icon is used and their Dimensions.

Comment: unfortunately, this is wrong for the nexus 10. it uses xxhdpi launcher icons, but it is an xdpi device.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

ldpi (120 dpi) 36 x 36 px
mdpi (160 dpi) 48 x 48 px
hdpi (240 dpi) 72 x 72 px
xhdpi (320 dpi)  96 x 96 px

Comment: Programmatically, how do I know which density my screen is?

Comment: Is the ratio always screensize / (10/3)?

Comment: DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); Your densitiy is dm.density (is a long)